# 1PSI per week air loss

Tags: tires, pressure

Is it normal to lose up to 1psi per week in a car tyre ? All my other tyres seem to retain the pressure but one tyre which I had a puncture plugged months ago seems to lose just under 1psi per week

Comment: So the puncture was not fully plugged? Did the loss start immediately after the puncture was "fixed"? Is there possibly another small hole from the incident?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the plug wasn't plugging properly as one day I could hear air coming out, put some  liquid ontop of the plug and it was leaking. Got the tyre replaced in the end

Answer (score 0):

Losing air over time is fairly normal, however, losing 1psi per week seems a little bit excessive. You can check to see if the where the tire was fixed is leaking air by spraying the area down with soapy water. If it's leaking, it will bubble. If it is leaking, you can always check with the shop which did the work for you and see if they will warrant their work. If not, you'll most likely just need to continue putting air in the tire weekly or however often you feel it needs to be added. It may just be one of those things.